# How to hide TabBar Text in TabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using TabNavigator from 'react-navigation'. I want to hide or remove Text under icons.

[image]

Here is a part of TabNavigator. (I'm using Expo)

```
    Camera: {
      screen: CameraScreen,
    },
    Noti: {
      screen: NotificationScreen,
    },
    Menu: {
      screen: MenuStackNavigator,
    },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
         header: null, <<<
         tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                     ...
         },
     }),
     header: null, <<<-
     headerMode: 'none',  <<--       
     tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
     tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
     animationEnabled: false,
     swipeEnabled: false,
     backBehavior: 'none',
```

And this is CamaraScreen

```
class CameraScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Camera'
  }
```

Comment: @johnbeck How can you show the image as the footer. The above-mentioned images are icons. I need to show the image as a footer. kindly provide your inputs. I am new to react native. I tried with some code snippets, but it does not work. kindly update your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064125/how-to-set-images-in-the-footer-text-under-tabnavigation-using-react-native

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can hide the label by specifying `showLabel: false` for the `tabBarOptions` object:

```
backBehavior: 'none',
tabBarOptions: {
    showLabel: false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the label by specifying tabBarShowLabel: false for the screenOptions object:

````
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "#000000", borderTopWidth: 0 },
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
      }}```
````