# How to set images in the footer text under TabNavigation using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to set footer which has image and text on all pages. I have used react native TabNavigator. The issue is footer text was shown in Uppercase and also the background color doesn't change and unable to set image in the footer.

```
  {
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'white',
    inactiveTintColor: 'black',
    activeBackgroundColor: 'darkgreen',
    inactiveBackgroundColor: 'green',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
    return (
    <Image
    source={('.../.../image/png')}
    style={{ tintColor }}
    /> 
}
});
```

How does the image will be set in the footer?

I am new to react native.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure about directory structure, but `triple` dots in `source` something that caught my attention, can u try by replacing to `source={('../../image/png')`, `double` dot notation.

Comment: I have given the image url in image source

Answer (score 1):

**TabNavigator** has an option init that you can design Icon with Label footer...
here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator , TabNavigator , TabBarBottom } from 'react-navigation';
import { Image , Text } from 'react-native';
import styles from './assets/style';


import Home from './pages/Home';
import Article from './pages/Article';

HomeStack = StackNavigator({
    Home : { screen : Home },
    Article : { screen : Article }
})



import Camera from './pages/Camera';
import Follow from './pages/Follow';
import HomeUser from './pages/HomeUser';
import Profile from './pages/Profile';
import Seach from './pages/Search';


export default App = TabNavigator({
    Profile : {
        screen : Profile,
        navigationOptions : {
            tabBarIcon : <Image source={require('./assets/images/react-native.png')}  style={styles.tabNavigatorProfileIcon} />
        }
    },
    Follow : {
        screen : Follow,
        navigationOptions : {
            tabBarIcon : <Image source={require('./assets/images/follow.png')}  style={styles.tabNavigatorProfileIcon} />
        }
    },
    Camera : {
        screen : Camera,
        navigationOptions : {
            tabBarIcon : <Image source={require('./assets/images/camera.png')}  style={styles.tabNavigatorProfileIcon} />
        }
    },
    Serach: {
        screen : Seach,
        navigationOptions : {
            tabBarIcon : <Image source={require('./assets/images/search.png')}  style={styles.tabNavigatorProfileIcon} />
        }
    },
    HomeUser : {
        screen : HomeUser,
        navigationOptions : {
            tabBarIcon : <Image source={require('./assets/images/home.png')}  style={styles.tabNavigatorProfileIcon} />
        }
    }
},{
    tabBarOptions : {
        showLabel : false,
        activeTintColor : 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
        inactiveTintColor : 'rgba(0,0,0,.3)'
    },
    tabBarComponent : TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition : 'bottom'
})
```

and if you want to set icon install `icon-vectors` import and use it instead of Image!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I use this inside a stack navigator in a single file(StackNavigator and Tab Navigator? And also how can set the different headers in the stack navigator.

Comment: I have different headers text, but has the same images will be seen slightly above the two corner of the header. More than 1 image will be present in that if we click that image it needs to navigate to another page.

Comment: Image doesn't show by the navigation option.   navigationOptions : {
            tabBarIcon : <Image source={require('./assets/images/search.png')}  style={styles.tabNavigatorProfileIcon} />
        }
    }                                                                                                                                       What is the styleguide given in the tabNavigatorProfileIcon by you.@Hamed Keshavarz

Comment: It's about changing text and styles.tabNavigatorProfileIcon is StyleSheet I import from other class. This is not a function it's customize to you @Jes

Comment: Images are not displayed in the footer @Hamed

Answer (score 0):

Issue get resolved when interchanging the style guide as

```
navigationOptions : {
    tabBarIcon : 
         <Image
           style={{width: 25, height:20,paddingTop:0}}
           source={{uri: './assets/images/search.png'}}
        />
        }
```